# IPV6 on Subdomain

Tags: nginx, dns, ipv6, centos6, vhosts

i want to use ipv4 on domain, and ipv6 for subdomain. i already set A record @ and WWW to ipv4 and AAAA record Trial for ipv6
example for this case my domain is example.com and my subdomain trial.example.com

i can access my domain now, but not for subdomain. for info i use centminmod and host to DO, my registrar from namecheap. i already change NGINX_IPV='y'
and here my vhost for subdomain

```
 server {
listen 80;
server_name trial.example.com;
listen [2604:180:1::fd2c:e4xx]:80 ipv6only=on;
return 301 $scheme://trial.example.com$request_uri;

access_log /home/nginx/domains/trial.example.com/log/access.log combined buffer=256k flush=60m;
error_log /home/nginx/domains/trial.example.com/log/error.log;

root /home/nginx/domains/trial.example.com/public;
location ~ (?:^|/)\. {
deny all;
} 

location / {

}

include /usr/local/nginx/conf/staticfiles.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/php.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/drop.conf;
include /usr/local/nginx/conf/vts_server.conf;
}
```

any suggest how to fix this? am i missed something? any help would appreciate. thanks

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove
`return 301 $scheme://trial.example.com$request_uri;`
Disable web browser cache and try again.